# Dereferencing an array within a struct being used by ptread_create

Tags: c, struct, pthreads, dereference

My ThreadData struct:

```
typedef struct threadData {
    pthread_t *ths;
} threadData;
```

Where *ths is an array of `pthread_t`.

Now, I create a thread that uses as action the following function, which creates a new thread in ths[1]

```
void *rootThread(threadData *d) {
    pthread_t *b = (*d).ths;
    pthread_create(*(b+1),NULL,someRandomFunction,NULL);
}
```

But that doesn't seem to work.

I'm not sure if I'm dereferencing the pthread_t element well. Please help!

Thanks, :).

Comment: How are you allocating your struct treadData? Currently it seems like you are creating member ths of thread data just to be a pointer, without allocating memory for it. rootThread gets a pointer to threadData. so use it as pthread* b = d->ths further pthread_create wants a pointer to pthread_t, thus don't derefenence it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like (for example) you are not allocating. You have to do something like this:

```
void* Thread(void* theCUstom);

pthread_t* threadHandle = malloc(sizeof(pthread_t));
pthread_mutex_t mutex; // mutex lock
pthread_attr_t attr;   // thread attributes
pthread_mutex_init(&mutex, NULL);
pthread_attr_init(&attr);
unsigned long errRes = pthread_create(threadHandle, &attr, Thread, yourCustom);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't maintain an index to which pthread_t to use that way.  b+1 will be constant every time you re-enter the rootThread().  You probably need a separate index variable in threadData, or a second pointer that can iterate through the list.  Either that, or don't make a temporary variable pthread_t *b.

```
typedef struct threadData {
    pthread_t *ths;
    int thsIdx;
} threadData;

void *rootThread(threadData *d) {
    pthread_create( &d->ths[d->thsIdx++],NULL,someRandomFunction,NULL);
}
```

Or your way:

```
 void *rootThread(threadData *d) {
    pthread_create( d->ths, NULL, someRandomFunction, NULL);
    ++d->ths; // this is nasty because you lose the pointer to the beginning of the array.
}
```